# Select multiple anchor points in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

I am watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KE2YVih0bAI) tutorial but I can't figure out how to select multiple anchor points and move them around.

Answer (score 4):

1 - Select `Direct Selection` tool (`a` key)

2 - Hold `shift` button

3 - Click on the anchor points holding `shift` key

Answer (score 1):

You can select more than one anchor point using **Shift(Windows os) or Command(Mac os)**. **Hold shift key or Command key** and select points.